# Nuget restore failed with "Packages not compatible" error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm not sure exactly what got updated in my solution but I am receiving a lot of errors when I try to build. The Error List in Visual Studio has a bunch of errors like this one:

> Package System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.10 is not compatible with portable45-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7). Package System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.10 supports:
>
> - dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0)
> - dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
> - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
> - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
> - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
> - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
> - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
> - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)

It says this for various System and Microsoft namespaced packages. At the end of my Build output it says:

> One or more packages are incompatible with
> .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7 (win10-x86-aot). NuGet
> package restore failed.

However, my solution still builds and runs fine even though the errors show up. How can I get rid of the errors in the error list and where did they come from? In the Error List it does not say what project, file, or line number the error was caused by.

Comment: That's a likely a cache problem either on the NuGet or the Visual Studio -side. Try closing Visual Studio and clearing both caches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use 4.0.11, which supports .NET Platform Standard,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.xml.xmlserializer

Second, update your NuGet VS addin to the latest version, so that it can properly resolve the relationship between PCL and .NET Platform Standard.

Comment: I have nuget 3.5.0 which looks like it's beta. I'm not sure how I got that but I'm going to try and roll back to 3.4.4 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Reverting to nuget 3.4.4 did not fix the problem

Comment: Sounds like the concept has been ready but the tooling is not, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md

Comment: I also tried moving what I think is the offending project to .NET Platform Standard but ended up going from 500+ errors to 1000+... guess I need to do more reading. The new architecture is so confusing.